# Wagtail pagination issue - wagtailcore.views.serve - Wagtail 0.8.6 - Django 1.7.7

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, wagtail

I'm using Wagtail, a lightweight django CMS. I upgraded Wagtail to 0.8.6 (Django from 1.6.5 to 1.7.7), I have a that basically display a list of news objects:

```
http://localhost:8020/news/
```

It uses django's paginator, so if I try to access to the next page:

```
http://localhost:8020/news/2/
```

I have an error:

```
ValueError at /news/2/
need more than 1 value to unpack
```

this is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8020/news/1/

Django Version: 1.7.7
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
 'compressor',
 'taggit',
 'modelcluster',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'preventconcurrentlogins',
 'django_medusa',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore',
 'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
 'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
 'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
 'wagtail.wagtailusers',
 'wagtail.wagtailimages',
 'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
 'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
 'wagtail.contrib.wagtailmedusa',
 'myapp',
 'django_extensions')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'preventconcurrentlogins.middleware.PreventConcurrentLoginsMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/views.py" in serve
  20.     page, args, kwargs = request.site.root_page.specific.route(request, path_components)

Exception Type: ValueError at /news/2/
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Any idea of what can cause this?
with the previous setup (`wagtail 0.5, Django 1.6.5`) it was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably got a `route()` method on your news page mode that returns an HttpResponse. This was deprecated in 0.4, and support for it was fully removed in 0.6:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/0.4.html#page-route-method-should-now-return-a-routeresult

You'll need to rewrite this into a `route()` method that returns a RouteResult object, and a separate `serve()` method to return the HttpResponse, as detailed here:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/core_components/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-route-method